# Display the previous date for a user in an additional column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of users and a list of review dates corresponding to each user, the user can have multiple reviews relating to them. What I need to do is create an additional column that shows me the users previous review date, if they don't have a previous review I need it to be null.
An example of the result I require is shown below with the column in bold being the column I want to add:

| User       | Review Date      | **Previous Review Date**    
| -----      | --------------   | ------------------------ 
| 1122334    | 01/01/2022       | **06/06/2021** 
| 1122334    | 06/06/2021       | **06/01/2021** 
| 1122334    | 06/01/2021       | **null** 
| 2244668    | 01/10/2021       | **01/04/2021** 
| 2244668    | 01/04/2021       | **null** 
| 3344556    | 10/11/2021       | **10/03/2021** 
| 3344556    | 10/03/2021       | **null**

You can see in the example, that the **previous review date** for the user on row 1 will be the  same users **review date** on row number 2

I have tried using the below:

```
select user, lead(review_date) over order(order by user,review_date desc) as Previous_review_date
```

this  code works until I need  it to be a null value in which case it will simply add the previous review date from an unrelated user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add `partition by user` instead of `order by user`

Comment: you could use a case expression to compare the review_date to the analytic and when same set it to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure `OUTER APPLY` would work here as well using a limit.

Note this could be useful if you need more than just a single column of data.

[some docs - outer apply](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1#outer-apply-join)

[ask tom - LINQ, cross/outer apply](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9530807800346558418)

In essence outer apply will run sub query once for each row in table A correlating the results between the two.  Since we limit and order the results; we'll only get 1 record back whose review date is less than the review date.  Now as an outer, we keep all records from A and only show results from Z when they exist.  So the Z.review_date will be null when no such date/user can be correlated.

```
SELECT A.user, A.Review_date Z.review_date as Previous_review_Date
FROM TABLE A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT review_date 
             FROM Table B on A.User=B.User and B.Review_date < a.Review_Date 
             ORDER BY review_Date Desc 
             FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY) Z
```

Depending on volumn of data one approach vs the other can be more efficient.  (See ask tom article)

Using your current approach:

`SELECT A.user, A.Review_Date, lead(A.Review_date) over (partition by A.User ORDER BY A.Review_Date DESC) FROM TABLE A`

The reason your's isn't working is because it's ordering ALL records by date; not those specific to a user.  So you need to "partition" the data to each user and only order that users' review dates.

Answer (score 0):

you need to partition the data to identify the lead value

```
select user, lead(review_date) over order(partition by user order by review_date desc) as Previous_review_date
```